# CoNLL 2012 Format in Python 2.7

Tags: python, text, machine-learning, nltk

I'm trying to output a .conll file that I can run on another script to get some evaluations.

To do this, I need the format to be in CoNLL 2012. Having looked into various ways to do this, I found CoreNLP do this but again I have no idea how the python wrapper works for this.

The format is on the bottom, I just find it very difficult to code this myself and was hoping there was an exisiting tool or library I could use. http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/data.html

I'm new to stackoverflow so please let me know if I'm not being detailed enough!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question would be easier to answer if you include a brief description or sample of the CONLL 2012 format. External links are dispreferred on this site (and as luck would have it, your link is *impossibly* slow right now.) Moreover, the site doesn't document the format in detail, and nobody wants to have to download a dataset just to understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm not sure how to do the format, I've tried to understand using the website but it's rather difficult. It's the only source that has the format...:(

Comment: Well you have the dataset, don't you? It seems to be tab-separated. You can edit your question and fill in the details.